# How to add two assemblies with the same name into an asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, include, facebook, facebooktoolkit

I'm using the Facebook Toolkit inside my Asp.net MVC Application. But now I like to use the Facebook c# Sdk as well, exspecially to test, which one works better for me.

Sadly they both consist of three assemblies that have the same name:

1. Facebook
2. Facebook.Web
3. Facebook.Web.Mvc

How can I still include both in my project?

Comment: does facebook REALLY have different assemblies with the same name?

Comment: There are not from Facebook, facebook distributes even a third one! Facebook Toolkit is from Microsoft and the Facebook C# Sdk is another open Source Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extern alias?

http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/07/4502.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to "wrap" one of the assemblies under a different name.